# `ddply` fails to apply logistic regression (GLM) by group to my dataset

Tags: r, regression, plyr, logistic-regression, glm

I'm working out the LD50 (lethal dosage) for multiple populations from different experiments using the `MASS` package. It's simple enough when I subset the data and do one at a time, but I'm getting an error when I use `ddply`. Essentially I need an LD50 for each population at each temperature.

My data looks somewhat like this:

```
# dput(d)
d <- structure(list(Pop = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), Temp = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("high", "low"), class = "factor"), 
Dose = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Dead = c(0L, 
11L, 12L, 14L, 2L, 16L, 17L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 17L, 15L, 9L, 20L, 
8L, 19L, 7L, 2L, 20L, 14L, 9L, 15L, 1L, 15L), Alive = c(20L, 
9L, 8L, 6L, 18L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 3L, 5L, 11L, 0L, 
12L, 1L, 13L, 18L, 0L, 6L, 11L, 5L, 19L, 5L)), .Names = c("Pop", 
"Temp", "Dose", "Dead", "Alive"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

The following works fine:

```
d$Mortality <- cbind(d$Alive, d$Dead)
a <- d[d$Pop=="a" & d$Temp=="high",]
library(MASS)
dose.p(glm(Mortality ~ Dose, family="binomial", data=a), p=0.5)[1]
```

But when I put this into `ddply` I get the following error:

```
library(plyr)
d$index <- paste(d$Pop, d$Temp, sep="_")
ddply(d, 'index', function(x) dose.p(glm(Mortality~Dose, family="binomial", data=x), p=0.5)[1])
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1

I can get the right LD50 when I use a proportion but can't figure out where I've gone wrong with my approach (and had already written this question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this will amaze you. But if you choose to use formula

```
cbind(Alive, Dead) ~ Dose
```

instead of

```
Mortality ~ Dose
```

the problem will be gone.

---

```
library(MASS)
library(plyr)

## `d` is as your `dput` result

## a function to apply
f <- function(x) {
  fit <- glm(cbind(Alive, Dead) ~ Dose, family = "binomial", data = x)
  dose.p(fit, p=0.5)[[1]]
  }

## call `ddply`
ddply(d, .(Pop, Temp), f)

#  Pop Temp        V1
#1   a high 2.6946257
#2   a  low 2.1834099
#3   b high 2.5000000
#4   b  low 0.4830998
#5   c high 2.2899553
#6   c  low 2.5000000
```

---

So what happened with `Mortality ~ Dose`? Let's set `.inform = TRUE` when calling `ddply`:

```
## `d` is as your `dput` result
d$Mortality <- cbind(d$Alive, d$Dead)

## a function to apply
g <- function(x) {
  fit <- glm(Mortality ~ Dose, family = "binomial", data = x)
  dose.p(fit, p=0.5)[[1]]
  }

## call `ddply`
ddply(d, .(Pop, Temp), g, .inform = TRUE)

#Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1
#Error: with piece 1: 
#  Pop Temp Dose Dead Alive Mortality
#1   a high    1    0    20        20
#2   a high    2   11     9         9
#3   a high    3   12     8         8
#4   a high    4   14     6         6
```

Now we we see that variable `Mortality` has lost dimension, and only the first column (`Alive`) is retained. For a `glm` with `binomial` response, if the response is a single vector, `glm` expects 0-1 binary or a factor of two levels. Now, we have integers 20, 9, 8, 6, ..., hence `glm` will complain

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1

There is really no way to fix this issue. I have tried using a protector:

```
d$Mortality <- I(cbind(d$Alive, d$Dead))
```

but it still ends up with the same failure.